# How can I show on screen an objetct list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

As I said in the question, I am trying to show on screen the values of a created object, but the output was the loop below instead of the list itself.

I have used the function `list.begin()` to check if the list it's the correct and effectively it shows `1`, so I don't understand why the values in the for loop are incorrect.

In summary, I don't find the mistake, so I would like to ask you where have I wrong.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Algo{

private:
    list <int> l;

public:
    Algo() {l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};}
    list <int> getList() {return l;}

};

int main()
{
    Algo a;
    list <int>::iterator it;
    it = (a.getList().begin()); 
    for(it; it != (a.getList().end()); it++)
    {
        cout << *it << "\n";
    }
}
```

Expected output: 1,2,3,4,5

Real output: 1

-1952806520

16122456

-1228957360

1

-1952806520

16122456

-1228957360

1 (infinite loop)

Comment: More to the point, without the change mentioned in the answer(s) `it=(a.getList().begin()); ` acquires an iterator to a *temporary* `list<int>`. The list is gone shortly thereafter, leaving a *dangling* iterator in its wake, the use of which will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others pointed out, you return a copy of the list.

1. Avoid names like `l`: they are very confusing. Use something like `_lst`.
2. Depending on your purpose you may want to return:

   - a copy – the client may modify the copy without changing the `_lst` member: `list <int> getList()`
   - a reference – avoids copying and the client may directly modify it: `list <int>& getList()`
   - or a constant reference – no copy and the client cannot modify it `_lst`: `const list <int>& getList() const`
3. If your only intention was to show the content of the list, just add a public member function and remove `getList`: `void dump() const`.
4. Instead of directly iterating thru `_lst` you may use the `copy` algorithm to copy the content of your list to the console

   ```
   void dump()
   {
     copy(_lst.begin(), _lst.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
   }
   ```
5. Your main becomes:

   ```
   int main()
   {
     Algo a;
     a.dump();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

in your getlist function you should be returning

```
list <int>& getList() { return l; }
```

and not

```
list <int> getList() { return l; }
```

which is copy of the list . Because of the way you are using that list

when you call it here

```
it=(a.getList().begin());
```

the get list function returns a copy of your list and iterator to its first element

now in the for loop

```
a.getList().end()
```

and more priciesly this part you are creating another copy and not the copy you used in the initalization above

now using the "&" in

```
list <int>& getList()
```

you are returning the actual list of your algo class & not a copy of it so the getlist function will return the same list for you everytime

Comment: `const list<int>&` would be better

Answer (score 1):

`list <int> getList()` returns a temporary copy of the incapsulated list. Each time you call `a.getList().end()` in the loop, you get an iterator of another copy of the list, that can't be compared with the initial iterator of `getList().begin()`. Thus the loop is infinite (iterators are not comparable) and output is junk (a temporary copy is not existing at output). Fix it by returning the reference to the incapsulated list:

```
list <int>& getList()
```